# How to link FullCalendar (2.5) draggables to external jQuery sortable

Tags: fullcalendar

Prior to FC 2.1, it used jQuery UI so setting the draggable() properties was fine. However now FC uses some internal logic for drag & drop (no jQ UI dependency) I'm seeing some issues when trying to link the draggable proxy to a sortable list elsewhere on the page.

Basically, I'm trying to create a calendar whereby I can drag elements OFF the FC area and onto a jQuery sortable list - and also the reverse operation (FROM the sortable list back on to the calendar)

It seems that if I use the FC callbacks to apply $.draggable() to the proxy, it messes up the drag & drop (doesn't higlight cells, sometimes the proxy is off-screen, that sort of thing)

Any ideas? I already checked out the demos on the FC page but they don't use sortables.

Comment: Share the fiddle url or your code in the question and add your jQuery tag. which browser u face this issue ?

Comment: I'll try to work something up - I already added my question to a (long) open ticket on github (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/820) that has similar issues